# Are questions that can potentially inspire a change in someone lifestyle considered "health advice" questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Help center clearly says no health advice allowed.

But can I ask questions with the intent of understand the processes in my body better? So armed with knowledge I understand signs my body sends to me letting me to find out how to handle them correctly.

So instead of asking "Is X healthy?" can I ask questions like "What effects of X have on [a biological process in human body]?"

Concrete example "What effects *drinking lot of water during meal* have on *digestion*?"

If the answers would say it have adverse effects on it one may consider drinking less during meals.

Another category is "Is [lifestyle habit] related to/causes [disease]? If yes, why?"

For example "Is *sitting for long time* related to *lower back pain*? If yes, why?"

This would insprite an answer that cites papers and show correlations, and explain statics and mechanical effects of sitting on the spinal cord, so that would allow one to find a posture avoids these effects and avoid the problem. Indirect health advice alert.

Or even more innocent looking question: "What factors determine the color of urine?"

Innocent looking but someone might enter the trap and would include the sentence in the answer "for example colorless urine may mean overhydration." Suggesting the colorless urine means I drank too much. Indirect health advice alert.

Answer (score 1):

If a question is general and biological in nature, you should be fine. However, if you general question is I have a friend who has X, how would this be handled? Then this may not fly since it is asking for advice. Also, note that if you do ask a question it shouldn't be simply a problem statement question asking others to do all the research. If you have looked it up, let us know what you found and what you need further elaboration on.